# Grails Spring Security Rest: restTokenValidationFilter does not work

Tags: grails, spring-security, spring-security-rest

I am using the [Spring Security Rest plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-rest) with Grails 3, but I am having trouble with the filterchain.

What I want to accomplish is that the security context is initiatized but anonymous access should still be possible.

My filterchain is

```
anonymousAuthenticationFilter, restTokenValidationFilter,restExceptionTranslationFilter
```

but on application startup I get the error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named ' restTokenValidationFilter' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:698)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1175)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1060)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils$_buildFilterChains_closure6.doCall(SpringSecurityUtils.groovy:794)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1021)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:426)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:442)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.collect(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:3124)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.collect(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:3095)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils.buildFilterChains(SpringSecurityUtils.groovy:794)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils$buildFilterChains$3.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin.doWithApplicationContext(SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin.groovy:682)
    at org.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugin.doWithApplicationContext(DefaultGrailsPlugin.java:524)
    at org.grails.plugins.AbstractGrailsPluginManager.doPostProcessing(AbstractGrailsPluginManager.java:229)
    at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:231)
    at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:163)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:136)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:381)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:335)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:855)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:55)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:365)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:354)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at com.me.Application.main(Application.groovy:8)
```

I checked and the plugin contains the RestTokenValidationFilter class, so I don't understand, why the bean is not found.

To get to the bottom of this I tried adding the class to the `resource.groovy` file but it still does not work.

Is the problem in my filterchain or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution 1 minute after posting :/

The correct filter chain ([from the docs](http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/2.0.0.M2/docs/index.html)) is:

```
anonymousAuthenticationFilter,restTokenValidationFilter,restExceptionTranslationFilter,filterInvocationInterceptor
```